# Would you use Sql Server Compact for a desktop application?

Tags: sql-server-ce

Does it make sense to use SQL Server Compact for a desktop application?

- How much data can it handle?
- Is it possible to use it with multiple users? What are the constraints?
- What happens when database files are broken? Is it possible to programmatically recover  or would it be easy to solve the problem remotely?

Comment: Why not use SQL Express instead?

Comment: We are trying to decide. SQL Express requires lots of more space, runs as a separate service (service count is a limitation for us), uses resources even when not being used, requires msi installation etc.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I certainly would (and do).  SQL Compact (SQLCE) has a distinct advantage in some scenarios.  Now it's in no way meant to be a replacement for SQL Server.  It doesn't scale, it isn't made to run thousands of concurrent connections, it's not designed for reporting services, etc, etc.

But it has a *tiny* footprint. Installing is a matter of just copying over DLLs.  Backing it up is a simple file copy. And it can be wicked fast for storage and retrieval if you're using table direct or BCP. Oh, and it's free. If you just need a local data store for an app, SQL Server is a pain to deploy and configure.  SQLCE is simple.  Plus it can play in the same sandbox as a full SQL Server as a replication subscriber (which most other small DBs can't).

Edit: Forgot to answer your specific questions:

- How much data can it handle?
  In terms of what? DB size?  Throughput?  Table size? Row size?
  My experience is that I've run the DB out to a a few hundred MB with no issue.  I think it can hold 4GB (as of 4.0).  Throughput is directly related to how you're putting data in or taking it out.  We're using it in a solution where we're capturing 1k rows a second with no problem.  You can have 1024 columns and a max row size of 8k.
- Multiple users?  Well it can handle multiple simulataneous connections (as of 3.5), so yes, that should work.  I've used multiple connections from one user, never from multiple.
- Broken databases?  Define "broken".  The engine has a "compact and repair" method.  It's a file like any other - how do you fix a broken executable?  I've not seen any corruptions in the field, if that's what you're asking (well we did on one CE device that had a bad storage card, but that's not the engine's fault).

Comment: Broken: corrupted db file. For e.g. what happens if the computer suddenly shuts down? Can the db file be corrupted? If that happens, can it be recovered automatically?

Comment: The database is like any other file.  If you have it open and are writing to it when you pull power then sure, that can cause corruption.  The same can be said with any database.  The engine itself is ACID, and we've had decent success with the Repair function for corruptions in testing.

Comment: Once we discovered SqlCeDataReader and SqlCeResultSet I absolutely adore CE. It's wicked fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a small database use something like SQLLite.

But here is an  [article about using compact edition on a server](http://blog.wharton.com.au/2007/10/sql-server-compact-edition-multi-user.html)

Answer (score 0):

I used it for one application and it worked well. The only issue I had is that, for some reason, SQL Server 2005 Management Studio does not support all the designer features for the latest release of SQL Server CE (e.g. you cannot edit tables, for instance). You have to use the 2008 version I think.

It's fast enough, but admittedly I used it for small data sets.